# Changing background color and color of text

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors

Say I had a few numbers in a list:

```
listt = [2, 4, 6]
```

Is there any way to do something that would change the background color  and color of each number depending on which number it is. For example:

```
for i in range(3):
    if listt[i] == 2:
        # make background color green and make number red
    elif listt[i] == 4:
        # make background color orange and make number green
    elif listt[i] == 6
        # make background color red and make number orange
    print(nlistt[i])
```

Is there any way to do this and if not with both background and regular color can you do 1 of the 2. Also this should be in the console and not in a new window like pygame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in terminal with colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I wan't to know how to change the color depending on an item in the list

Comment: Do you want it on a new window(ex pygame,pyglet) or in the console?

Comment: I want it in the console

Comment: @J.Doe you can just use what is on alex's suggestion... its right there with 57 upvotes at least how to print with colour, actually and with background

Comment: How can I use it with my code so that if a number is 2, 4, or 6 it prints different results??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply the color code to what you want to print, the color code could be found in the post @Alex Taylor [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors).

```
listt = [2, 4, 6]
nlistt = listt.copy()
for i in range(3):
    if listt[i] == 2:
        # make background color green and make number red
        nlistt[i] = '\033[1;31;42m' + str(nlistt[i]) + '\033[0m'
    elif listt[i] == 4:
        # make background color orange and make number green
        nlistt[i] = '\033[1;32;43m' + str(nlistt[i]) + '\033[0m'
    elif listt[i] == 6:
        # make background color red and make number orange
        nlistt[i] = '\033[1;33;41m' + str(nlistt[i]) + '\033[0m'
    print(nlistt[i])
```